# Do alternative browsers use their own rendering engine or Trident?

Tags: browser

I use IE mostly and Opera Mini a little bit. What I've been wondering, do Opera Mini and UC Browser use their own rendering engine (WebKit and ???) or are they more or less skins on the Trident engine?

Answer (score 1):

As this is still one of the most requested features on [Windows Phone UserVoice](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3772998-please-allow-third-party-webkit-based-browsers) I assume it is not yet possible or at least no one has tried to create browsers with rendering engines different from Trident. This might be due to the limited API access for native code. So Opera Mini and all the others are propably wrapping around an IE webview, yes.

Comment: Do you have any references for that?

Comment: I will check if I can find some official documentation for this - I think I saw this on MSDN some time ago.

Comment: Whilst it might not be trivial, I can't think of a technical restriction that would stop someone creating their own rendering engine, so would be interested in seeing why this would be the case.

Comment: Afaik there are still a lot of restrictions on what you can and can't do using native code. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any reliable information on this so I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the issue is that you cannot create a competitively fast JavaScript engine, due to restrictions that prevent Just In Time compilations and similar optimizations currently used by all of the browsers. Probably related - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1253307